# How to convert a file to a new type?

Tags: file-type

I have often used a site like http://jpg2pdf.com/ to do various pdf file manipulations.  I don't love the idea of sending sensitive information contained in some pdf to somebody else's server.

I want to build a command line tool (Windows or Linux, I will try to implement both eventually) that allows me to manipulate the file type locally, but I am having trouble finding resources on file extensions and file types at a low level, beyond how to change the file type with a GUI.

What are some good resources I could use to learn more about file types, specifically how to modify the extension in a way that Adobe could read a png, for example?

Comment: Changing filetypes is **very** non-trivial. You need to write software that can fully model every aspect of the source file type and know how to losslessly translate those concepts (or at least try to minimize information-theoretical losses) to the new format. For example, converting from MP3 to RIFF-Wave (*`.wav`) and back again, or from a PSD (layers, effects, non-RGB colour systems) to a PNG image (flat RGBA raster data).

Comment: Granted, most of those "ConvertFooToBar.com" websites actually work by taking pre-existing open-source programs and libraries (e.g. GhostScript, FFmpeg, VLC, Webkit, etc) and putting a pretty web frontend in front of them. If you want to do that then that's much easier.